# Dropbox ios does not call delegate from non-main threads

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've implemented a NSOperationQueue for each file upload to dropbox. I am setting the delegate for each operation that operation's thread. I do not get a callback to any of the delegate methods.

This same procedure works fine if use the main thread.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue? I'm having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that dropbox delegate is registered in another thread. I am using a NSOperation w/ NSQueue I just continue to poll that the operation is not complete.

```
while (_state != DropboxOperationStateFinished)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```